Showing the bounds of two specific symmetric matrices
Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, partitioned as:
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} A& B\\ B^T&C\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A$ is $k\times k$. Let $\alpha = \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^k a_{ij}$, $\beta = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^k b_{ij}$, and $\delta = \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n-k} c_{ij}$. Here $a_{ij}, b_{ij}, \text{ and } c_{ij}$ are the entries of $A, B, C$, respectively. Consider the matrix:
$$N = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\alpha}{k} & \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{k(n-k)}}\\ \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{k(n-k)}} & \frac{\delta}{n-k}\end{bmatrix}$$
I now want to show that $\lambda_{max}(M) \geq \lambda_{max}(N)$ and that $\lambda_{min}(M) \leq \lambda_{min}(N)$. Here, the $\lambda's$ represent that largest and smallest eigenvalues of $M$ and $N$ respectively. I am not exactly sure how to proceed.
My initial thought is to attempt to build $M$ from $N$ and use the interlacing theorem to deduce the result about the max and min eigenvalues. But that seems ineffective. It is also unclear to me why we would scale all the factors down, but surely that makes the proof simpler. Any help would be very appreciated!

the interlacing theorem is the way. There's an easy orthogonal $U$ such that  $N=U^TMU$

Thanks! I was certain that was the case, but evidently was not very confident.

Could you expand a bit more on $N = U^TMU$? Specifically, since $M$ and $N$ are of different dimensions, is your $M$ a specific iteration? Or is $U$ a rectangular matrix? I think that would make it not orthogonal anymore though. @Exodd

$U$ is orthogonal in the sense that it has orthogonal columns

Are you able to expand a bit more on this? Specifically, is $U$ an $n\times 2$ matrix? That is the only way I can make sense of your comment.

yes, it has 2 columns that have unit norm and are orthogonal to each other
